# Forcing linq-to-entities on an EF POCO entity related collection (to act like EntityCollection<>)

Tags: .net, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

In summary: What are my options for getting a LINQ query of an entity's child collection to use "LINQ-to-Entities" rather than "LINQ-to-Objects", to in other words, cause a query provider to be used that generates SQL rather than performing normal enumeration?  This is using EF5, DbContext, and POCO entities.

Another way to look at it is: How do I get the entity's child collections (of type ICollection<>) to act like the old-style EF1 entities' EntityCollection<> properties without changing all of my LINQ queries?

Here is my situation:

I have an Entity Framework 5 project that I'm switching over to use DbContext and POCO entities instead of ObjectContext and the default generated entities.

Throughout my code, I have queries that look like this:

```
var thirdEntities = from secondEntity in firstEntity.SecondEntities
    select secondEntity.ThirdEntity;
```

This used to result in only a single database hit, because firstEntity.SecondEntities was of type EntityCollection.  And this caused LINQ to Entities to be used, which translated the entire LINQ statement into SQL.

However, when I switched to using DbContext and POCOs, the above statement now results in numerous database hits.  Here is the POCO class property that causes the issue:

```
public class FirstEntity {
  public FirstEntity() {
    this.SecondEntities = new HashSet<SecondEntity>();
  }

  public virtual ICollection<SecondEntity> SecondEntities {get; set;}
}
```

This is because firstEntity.SecondEntities is now of type ICollection (which actual type of HashSet).  Since lazy loading is on, the database is hit to fill firstEntity.SecondEntities and then that result is enumerated X times to fill each instance of secondEntity.ThirdEntity.

One solution I found is to change the first query to:

```
var thirdEntities = from secondEntity in dbContext
    .Entry(firstEntity)
    .Collection(e => e.SecondEntities)
    .Query()
    select secondEntity.ThirdEntity;
```

However, I don't want to do this.  I'd rather change the POCO somehow so that I don't have to change all of my LINQ queries.

Comment: But `EntityCollection<T>` even doesn't implement `IQueryable<T>` and didn't in EF 1 either. All LINQ extension methods of `EntityCollection<T>` are inherited from `IEnumerable<T>`. How could a LINQ query applied to a collection that doesn't implement `IQueryable<T>` generate a SQL query? That's strange...

Comment: That is correct.  However, using EntityCollection<T> as the "root" collection in a LINQ query triggers the usage of linq-to-entities.

Comment: @Josh: No it does not. Even source code of EF shows that enumerator does not trigger L2E. The only way to get L2E with `EntityCollection<T>` is to use `CreateSourceQuery` as showed by @Slauma in the example. `CreateSourceQuery` is not used by EF internally. `CreateSourceQuery` is equivalent of `Entry.Collection` used by DbContext API.

Answer (score 3):

To my understanding and also tests I have run it is not correct that a LINQ query on an `EntityCollection<T>` is LINQ-to-Entities. In fact it is LINQ-to-Objects and runs in memory only, without creating SQL and touching the database (aside from lazy loading in EF >= 4.0).

As an example:

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    var firstEntity = ctx.FirstEntities.First(f => f.ID == 1);
    var thirdEntities = (from secondEntity in firstEntity.SecondEntities
                         select secondEntity.ThirdEntity).ToList();
}
```

Here the first query is LINQ-to-Entities of course and loads `firstEntity` from the database. The second query doesn't create a single SQL query that selects `ThirdEntity` as I have checked with SQL profiler. In EF 1 the second query will actually do nothing because `firstEntity.SecondEntities` hasn't been loaded eagerly in the first query (so the collection is empty) and EF 1 doesn't support lazy loading. In EF 4 a lazy loading query will be triggered to load the full collection and then one additional lazy loading query for each (unique) element in the collection to load `ThirdEntity` (I have tested this as well) - exactly the same behaviour you have observed when using POCOs.

The result is not surprising to me because `EntityCollection<T>` doesn't implement `IQueryable<T>`. The signature is:

```
public sealed class EntityCollection<TEntity> : RelatedEnd, ICollection<TEntity>,
    IEnumerable<TEntity>, IEnumerable, IListSource
```

All LINQ queries you perform on such a collection will use the extension methods of `IEnumerable<T>` which means: It is LINQ-to-Objects.

However, similar to your last code snippet you can enable LINQ-to-Entities/explicit loading by applying `CreateSourceQuery` to an `EntityCollection<T>`:

```
var thirdEntities =
    (from secondEntity in firstEntity.SecondEntities.CreateSourceQuery()
     select secondEntity.ThirdEntity).ToList();
```

`CreateSourceQuery` will return an `ObjectQuery<T>` that represents the SQL necessary to load the full navigation collection from the database. This query indeed can be refined to perform more filtering or selecting and it will be executed as LINQ-to-Entities in the database.

If you are sure that you have observed a different query behaviour for `EntityCollection<T>` vs. POCOs, it would help if you could provide a simple sample model for reproducing this. At the moment I have no idea how this could happen.